# I installed this extension algoliasearch for Catalog Search and use this like default search bug when running reindex, it shows a bug

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, algolia

I want to use Algolia search like the default search and disable Elasticsearch but when I run reindex, it shows a bug like this:

Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster

https://prnt.sc/gfXB_ZLXJ_Pm

I use Magento 2.4.5. Do I need to worry about it?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. **Catalog Search** index is at least used for product listing in both backend and frontend, so you should fix this issue by config the Elasticsearch.

Related documents:

- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/search/overview-search.html
- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/prerequisites/search-engine/configure-nginx.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm using Algolia search and I don't want to change it to Elasticsearch(Setup a new server, take more charge).

Comment: Looks like you still misunderstood, in both cases: whether you use Algolia Search or not, you still need Elastichsearch because other features require Elasticsearch: for instance: product listing in the category page and product grid in the Category edit page while Algolia **ONLY** supports "search" features: instant search in mini search, search result page.

Comment: In case you want to disable Elasticsearch engine, you can use this module: https://github.com/zepgram/module-disable-search-engine

Comment: Thank you so much @Tu Van, I think I will keep Elasticsearch extension turn on and use Algolia for search.

Comment: @DavidDuong No problems. That sound great!

Answer (score 1):

1). Please ensure that configuration of indexing queue as per the document
https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/magento-2/how-it-works/indexing-queue/?client=php

2). Can you please try to reindex with algolia cli commands and check for reindex

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think this is an index of Magento.